# Powershell Script Window Disappears

Tags: powershell, shortcut

My end goal is to create a keyboard shortcut that runs a powershell script. I followed what this guy is doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677467/launch-powershell-script-with-keyboard-hotkey). Right now, when I run the script from a PowerShell terminal, everything works just fine. But when I run it from the shortcut by double-clicking in the File Explorer (or keyboard shortcut), a new window appears with some kind of text in red but the window disappears before I have time to read anything. I'm sure I could fix the issue if I could read the message, but the window disappears too quickly. My .ps1 script and shortcut are saved to the Desktop.

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337229/powershell-window-disappears-before-i-can-read-the-error-message) that suggests adding the `-NoExit`switch, but this does not fix the issue for me.

I have tried changing the Execution Policy to `Bypass` and `Unrestricted` and neither made a difference.

I tried modifying my script to pause on the first line of code, but it doesn't get that far so I assume the issue is not with my script.

The shortcut's properties:

Target: `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\<script>.ps1`

Start in: `C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\`

[image: The script's properties window.]

I need to know why my script isn't running.

Please let me know what other information I left out and thanks in advance.

Comment: in your script, add `pause` at the very end to make the script stop & wait for a keypress. if the problem is deeper in the script than your original `pause`, that should allow you to read the message.

Comment: I have several pauses throughout the script, the first is on the first line of execution, and it still isn't stopping there.

Comment: Are you on a domain? 
If so it's likely that running unsigned scripts on the domain is controlled by group policy  What's the output of the command: Get-ExecutionPolicy -List ?

Comment: @tbriggs707 - since it aint stopping ... then the script itself is almost certainly NOT running. [*sigh ...*] what happens if you replace your PS1 file with a BAT file that has only a `pause` in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your symptom implies that **`C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\<script>.ps1` refers to a *nonexistent* script file**.

<sup>`<script>.ps1` is just a placeholder for the real filename.</sup>

Note: The use of environment-variable reference `%UserName%` *per se* is *not* a problem; *any* environment variable can be referenced this way, both in the `Target:` field (command line) and the `Start in:` field (working directory).
As an aside: Consider using `%USERPROFILE%`, or, more robustly,  `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` to refer to the current user's home directory<sup>[1]</sup>.

**Make sure that the path is correct, and try again.**

If you want to **troubleshoot an environment-variable-based path**, temporarily modify your command line as follows:

```bash
powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c 'C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\<script>.ps1'
```

<sup>`-File` was replaced with `-c` (`-Command`), and *single quotes* are used around the path, which makes PowerShell treat the content as a *literal string* to print.</sup>

The above will merely *print* the expanded script path.

---

As for the **root cause**:

**Debatably, PowerShell *always* exits the new process if the script file path passed to the  `-File` argument cannot be found - even if `-NoExit` is also present**.

The same problem exists - but only in *Windows PowerShell*, not PowerShell *Core* - if the file exists but *doesn't have extension `.ps1`*.

I've reported this behavior [in GitHub issue #10471](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10471).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>`%USERPROFILE%` and `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` by default point to the *same* directory (`C:\Users\%USERNAME%`), but can be configured point to point to *different* locations; `%USERPROFILE%` then points to a directory with *OS and application configuration data* only, whereas `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` points to the directory where the user's *desktop and documents* are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got this to work by using your troubleshooting advice and noticed that the file path was incorrect. I replaced 'C:\Users\%UserName%' with your more robust recommendation of '%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%'.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @tbriggs707; my pleasure. While not common, `%USERPROFILE%` and `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` can point to different locations - I've added a footnote to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `C:\Users\%UserName%\` to `%userprofile%\`. I don't believe that `%username%` works in shortcuts the way you are trying to use it.

Comment: I didn't change it substantially, I just made it more specific. It's still the same general idea. I don't see why you're saying it's unhelpful just because it's standard for them to be equivalent. If there's a possibility that it may not be, then why not notify them of that? Who know, maybe it could even be the *answer* they were looking for. Also you probably shouldn't have deleted the first couple comments because they are still relevant.

Comment: The original form of your answer erroneously claimed (albeit tempered with "I think") that use of `%username%` was _fundamentally unsupported_. The ensuing comment exchange was focused on disputing that claim.
Then you changed your answer to qualify it with "the way your are using it" - which is a substantial change.
Even that qualification is mere speculation, because, as stated, `C:\Users\%UserName%` and `%userprofile%` are equivalent in _standard installations_ of Windows.
What _may_ help is to point out that they _can_ differ, in _exceptional_ circumstances - see my previous comment.

Comment: As for deleting comments: To be clear: it wasn't _I_ who deleted comments - as a fellow SO user I don't have that power - it was _moderators_ who deleted them, based on my flagging them as "no longer needed".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `New-Shortcut` function I've [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547816/9898643) to create your shortcut:

```
$myDesktop     = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$myScriptPath  = Join-Path -Path $myDesktop -ChildPath 'YOUR PS1 SCRIPT FILE'

$shortcutProps = @{
    'ShortcutPath'     = Join-Path -Path $myDesktop -ChildPath 'Run PowerShell File.lnk'
    'TargetPath'       = '%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    'Arguments'        = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass', '-NoExit', '-NoLogo', ('-File "{0}"' -f $myScriptPath)
    'Description'      = "Run $myScriptPath"
    'WorkingDirectory' = $myDesktop
    'HotKey'           = 'Ctrl','Shift','F'
    'WindowStyle'      = 'Default'
}

New-Shortcut @shortcutProps
```

Besides the `-NoExit` switch, there are more options to leave the window open after the code has run.
For that have a look at [deadlydog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621106/9898643) and [the blog](https://blog.danskingdom.com/keep-powershell-console-window-open-after-script-finishes-running/) he wrote about that.

Comment: Interesting; interactively, I can't reproduce the `-File` problem, neither on Windows 7 nor Windows 10 (version 1903). Leaving `-File` out means that `-Command` is implied, which changes the semantics of the invocation in terms of argument handling (not an issue here) and exit-code reporting (potentially an issue) here. What OS are you observing the problem on, and do you also see it when creating the shortcut interactively?

Comment: @mklement0 I did this on Windows 7, PowerShell 5.1 When I added `-File` to the argument, the script ran but the window closed. Without it, just adding the quoted file path to the arguments array, the script ran and left the window open. I honestly have no idea why `-noexit` seems to be ignored if I include the `-File` parameter name..Although I tried several times it is possible I made some stupid typo each time. Will check again tomorrow as I'm on a phone right now.

Comment: Thanks, @Theo. I now believe that the problem is simply caused by passing a nonexistent script file path to `-File`.

Comment: @mklement0 And today.. I cannot reproduce the closing of the window myself anymore, so I must have made some typo yesterday and kept overlooking that. You're probably right about the non existing script file path. I have edited my answer and included the `-File`.